# angularjs . only email input doesn't sync

Tags: angularjs

========================================================

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content=""><meta name="author" content="">
<link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js">    </script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script><script src="js/main.js"></script></head><body>
<style>
    form {width: 300px;}
</style>
<div ng-app="registerapp">
<div ng-controller="ngController">
    <form novalidate class="simple-form">
        <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" class="form-control" placeholder='Enter Username' /><br />
        <input type="password" ng-model="user.password" class="form-control" placeholder='Enter password' /><br />
        <input type="email" ng-model="user.email"  class="form-control" placeholder='Enter Email'/><br />
        <input type="test" ng-model="user.test"  class="form-control" placeholder='Enter whatever'/><br />

        Gender: <input type="radio" ng-model="user.gender" value="male" />male
        <input type="radio" ng-model="user.gender" value="female" />female<br />

        <button ng-click="reset()" class="btn btn-primary">RESET</button>
        <button ng-click="update(user)"  class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        <button ng-click="reset()"  class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
    </form>
    <pre>form = {{user | json}}</pre>
    <pre>master = {{master | json}}</pre>
</div>

</div>
<script>
    var registerapp = angular.module('registerapp', []);
     registerapp.controller("ngController",    function Controller($scope) {
    $scope.master = {};
    $scope.update = function(user) {
        $scope.master = angular.copy(user);
    };
    $scope.reset = function() {
        $scope.user = angular.copy($scope.master);
    };
    $scope.reset();
});
```

==================================================

with above testing code.

other values sysc with {user: json} ..

only email doesn't sync with bottom part. ..

what's wrong ?

I don't understand...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works when  you put in an email address. I think it looks for the '@' character. The type='email' filters out data that doesn't match the type.